# Bootstrap login with javascript

Tags: javascript, git, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Javascript and I need to validate a log-in form with Bootstrap, the thing is not validating the password in the script.

https://jsfiddle.net/98uqsvu2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_info()
{
var user = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
    if(user == "test@gmail.com")
    {
        if(pass == "123")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
</script>
```

git: https://gist.github.com/Adaryn/6c38cfafd5e95d8a0bba508a33cebec7

Comment: What is your actual validation logic?  You've hard coded a single user and password here.  By the way, I was able to login to your Fiddle.  You might want to take that link down to avoid spam.

Answer (score 0):

@Adaryn
Since I cannot comment, I posted it as an answer.

I made the following changes to the fiddle and I was able to execute the code.

- Removed the link href's from your HTML.
- Added the closing body tag.
- Moved the script from the javascript code section and pasted it just above the closing body tag.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kow9qLq3/).

```
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" form role="form" action="hola.html" name="formlogin" method="post" class="login-form" onsubmit="check_info()">

    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_info()
{
    var user = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
    if(user == "test@gmail.com")
    {
        if(pass == "123")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code. also added jsfiddle

```
document.getElementById("submit-form").addEventListener("click", check_info);

function check_info() {
  var user = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
  if (user == "test@gmail.com" && pass == "123") {
    alert("email and password is valid!!!");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("email and password is NOT valid!!!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/damaxrss/**